# would Cassandra write be successful in the following situation?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I have two datacentres with 3 machines each. the replication factor is DC1:3, DC2:3 and all the inserts are made with write consistency = all.

So all data exists on all nodes (this is done to get reads to be the fastest).

But are there other problems with this set up that I might be missing? (except for writes being slow which im fine with)

For example, **if a single node is down would all my writes fail?** (Or can cassandra note down the writes for the failed node somewhere and bring it up to speed once its up?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a single node were down, then all your writes would fail.  The consistency level specifies how many replicas you require for the write to be successful.  So if you say ALL, and every node is a replica, then all the nodes would need to be up for it to succeed.

Usually you would do your writes with a lower consistency, like ONE.  Cassandra will still write the data to all the nodes if they are up.  If some of them are down, then the data may still get written to them (once they are back up) via hinted handoffs, read repair chance, and scheduled repairs.